# Problem Confusion - Solution to SO DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I do not understand why my answer for [image]

is wrong. Does anyone else get the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

I get exactly the same result.

It is possible that the system is not grouping terms and leaving it as:

$$y(x) = e^{-x} + \dfrac{x e^x}{4} - \dfrac{e^x}{4} + e^{-x} x \ln(x)$$

It is even possible they have $\ln x$ as the more general $\log x$ with natural log understood.

At least you have the correct result and can share that with the instructor.